# How to Show horizontal submenu in Bootrap Navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I would like to show my bootstrap vertical dropdown menu into horizontal view.
That means dropdwon list items should be show in a same line.

Currently dropdown menu items showed in a dropdown list with vertical view. but i need the same line  horizontal view when the user click the button.

Current Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkQ4T.png)

expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1bUw.png)

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                          <div class="navbar-header">

                              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                          </div>

                          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                  <li class="active">
                                      <a href="#">Link</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#">Link</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="dropdown">
                                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Action</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li class="divider">
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li class="divider">
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                              <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input class="form-control" type="text">
                                  </div>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                      Submit
                                  </button>
                              </form>
                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                                  <li class="dropdown">
                                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Action</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li class="divider">
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>

                      </nav>
```

Comment: The easiest would be to not use <li> in your .dropdown-menu, rather us <span>.

Comment: tried with <span> tag.. still its show in a one by one. i need a items in inline (same row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inline-block css we have use span instead of listing the items(li)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><span><a href="#">Page 1</a></span>|
          <span><a href="#">Page 2</a></span>|
          <span><a href="#">Page 3</a></span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Malathy Venkatesan.. its works.. but if it is listed in <li> tag instead of using <span> its better for me..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1s75buv9/5/

```js
var pos = parseInt($('.linedUp').closest('.dropdown').position().left);
calcWidth = function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
   var width = 0;
    var maxWidth = $(document).width() - pos;
   $('.linedUp li').each(function(){
      width += parseInt($(this).outerWidth()) + 2;
      if( maxWidth < width){
       width -= parseInt($(this).outerWidth());
      }
      
    });
    $('.linedUp').css({
     width: width
    });
  }, 0);
   
}
```

```css
.linedUp > li{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="calcWidth()">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu linedUp">
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Action 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

I created using **li**, then calculated the width dynamically.